# How to perform button's onclicklistner event on Fragment which is add on runtime (FATAL EXECPTION ERROR)?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Currently I am working on map in which I need to perform button's onclicklistner event on fragment which is inflate during run time. Means button is already present in current activity and by this button I need to use `onclicklistner` on runtime added fragment.

Here is my code:

Map.java: in which I add fragment.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    Frontpage fragment6 = new Frontpage();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment6);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}
```

This is frontpage.java class. I add this class in map.java as a fragment.

```
package com.example.vroomroutess;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.vroomroutess.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Frontpage extends Fragment {

SharedPreferences file;
DatabaseHandler db;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
float[] results = new float[100];
List<Double> list;
List<Double> list1;
int i;
public Frontpage() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapfragment, container,false);


    file = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Ryans_play", getActivity().MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(getActivity());
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
} catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
} 
     db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

    //ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
    /** Simply to show the maps */

    LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    final Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    // LatLng userLocation = new
    // LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();



    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //LatLng ltlng = new LatLng(lati, lngi);

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
    getCurrentLocation();


    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); 




    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

            // Already 10 locations with 8 waypoints and 1 start location
            // and 1 end location.
            // Upto 8 waypoints are allowed in a query for non-business
            // users
            if (markerPoints.size() >= 10) {
                return;
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(point);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(point);

            /**
             * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and for
             * the end location, the color of marker is RED and for the rest
             * of markers, the color is AZURE
             */
            if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            } else {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            }

            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            googleMap.addMarker(options);

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}   

void getCurrentLocation() {
    Location myLocation = googleMap.getMyLocation();
    if (myLocation != null) {
        double dLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double dLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
                .position(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude))
                .title("My Location"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                dLatitude, dLongitude), 16));


        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude)).zoom(15.5f).bearing(0)
                        .tilt(25).build()

                ), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // Your code here to do something after the Map is rendered
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // ""+location.getLatitude() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // Your code here to do something after the Map rendering is
                // cancelled

            }
        });
        Log.i("Move camrasj4444444444444444444", "mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm");

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch the current location",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

}





}
```

I need to perform onclick event like this in map.java:

```
drawmap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mapbutton);
drawmap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




            googleMap.clear();
            if (markerPoints.size() < 0) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You don't selected any ponit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker

                list = new ArrayList<Double>();
                list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
                PolylineOptions po = new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true);
                po.width(5);
                po.color(Color.RED);
                for (i = 0; i < markerPoints.size(); i++) {

                    LatLng ltlng1 = markerPoints.get(i);

                    System.out.println("value of i----" + i);

                    list.add(markerPoints.get(i).latitude);
                    list1.add(markerPoints.get(i).longitude);

                    options.position(ltlng1);

                    if (i == 0) {
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                    } else if (markerPoints.size() - 1 == i) {
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                    } else {
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                    }

                    // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                    googleMap.addMarker(options);

                    po.add(ltlng1);

                }
                googleMap.addPolyline(po);

                System.out.println("list size----------" + list.size());

                for (int j = 0; j < list.size() - 1; j++) {
                    int a;
                    if (j == list.size()) {
                        a = j - 1;
                    } else {
                        a = j + 1;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Value of a==" + a + "Value of j=="
                            + j);

                    Location.distanceBetween(list.get(j), list1.get(j),
                            list.get(a), list1.get(a), results);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "distance ====" + results[j], Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                }

            }

        }
    });
```

But this give me error. My logcat:

```
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200): Process: com.example.vroomroutess, PID: 2200
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at com.example.vroomroutess.Map$4.onClick(Map.java:186)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-06 14:25:04.825: E/AndroidRuntime(2200):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 14:25:04.825: W/dalvikvm(2200): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2cbeb20)
```

How to fetch added fragments object in current activity? Fragment successfully added. Error give `nullpointerexeception`. and it also give me an error at `googlemap.clear();` in `map.java` means I am not able to fetch map at fragment which is add in `Map.java` at runtime.  So how can I solve this problem.? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your Map.java line 186?

Comment: update your line of assignment to....                            drawmap = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapbutton);

Comment: You should work with the fragment's child views inside of the fragment class itself. Trying to set a click listener in your activity for a view that is in your fragment will lead to problems.

Comment: @joao2fast4u googlemap.clear(); you can see it in Button click event in last code snippet

Comment: @zgc7009 How to solve this problem

Comment: try putting the drawmap.onclick functionality in your fragment... likely in onCreateView right above your googleMap.setOnMapClickListener functionality.

Comment: @zgc7009 I can't use `drawmap.onclick` functionality in fragment because my button is available in `activity_map` layout which is set in `map.java` and opposite this in fragment class `R.layout.mapfragment` which does not has this button. and I also can't use this button in this `mapfragment`.

Comment: So the button `drawmap` has nothing to do with your fragment, sorry I thought it was in your fragment based on the question. The error it seems in this case is that you are doing the opposite if what I thought. Your googleMap is null because you are trying to set it incorrectly. Move the `googleMap` initialization and functionality to your `Map.java` Activity at the end of onCreate. I will be 100% honest though I am not entirely sure that is the issue as I haven't been able to really look through all of the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52131/discussion-between-android-developer-and-zgc7009)